# Слайд калькулятор

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть два `input` и два `popup` окна.

В случае ввода в оба поля допустимых значений, и если значение справа больше, чем значение слева (значение справа – значение слева), появляется модальное окно с классом `popup-economy`, и введенные числа записываются в два `div`'a c с классом `.price-left` и `.price-right`, а разница записывается в абзац с классом `.economy`, а также вычисляется значение в процентах ( (значение справа – значение слева)*100 / значение справа) и сумма записывается в `div` с классом `.sum`.

В случае ввода в оба поля допустимых значений, и если значение справа меньше, чем значение слева, появляется модальное окно с классом `.warning`, и в класс `.economy` записывается "Возможно вы ошиблись".

Все это должно срабатывать при клике на `button`. Лучше всего подойдет вариант на jquery.

```
<input class="form-left" type="text">
<input class="form-right" type="text">
<button class="btn-select">Посчитать</button>

<div class="popup-economy" style="display: none">
    <div class="price-left"></div>
    <div class="price-right"></div>
    <p class="economy"></p>
    <div class="sum"></div>
</div>

<div class="warning" style="display: none">
    <div class="price-left"></div>
    <div class="price-right"></div>
    <p class="economy"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Пример своей реализации в студию, что не получилось, с чем проблемы? И зачем здесь джеквери?

Comment: Можно и на ванильном js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(".btn-select").click(function() {
  $('.warning').hide(); //Прячем блок warning
  $('.popup-economy').hide(); //Прячем блок popup-economy
  var left = parseInt($('.form-left').val()); //Получаем значение из input form-left, чрезе parseInt возвращяем только число
  var right = parseInt($('.form-right').val()); //Аналогично
  if (right > left) { //Проверяем, что правое число больше левого
    $('.popup-economy').fadeIn(); //Показываем блок popup-economy
    var economy = right - left; //Вычитаем из правого значения левое
    $('.economy').text(economy); //И записываем его в economy
    $('.price-left').text(left); //Записываем левое значение в price-left
    $('.price-right').text(right); //Записываем правое значение в price-right
    var sum = (right - left) * 100 / right; //Считаем процент
    $('.sum').text(sum); //Записываем процент
  } else { //Если правое значение меньше левого
    $('.warning').fadeIn(); //Показываем блок warning
    $('.economy').text('Возможно вы ошиблись'); //И записываем в  economy текст 'Возможно вы ошиблись'
  }
});
$(".form-left").keyup(function() {//Отслеживаем нажатие клавиш
  if ($(".form-left").val() && $(".form-right").val()) {//Проверяем заполненны ли поля
    $('.btn-select').attr('disabled', false);//Включаем кнопку
  } else {
    $('.btn-select').attr('disabled', true);//Выключаем кнопку
  }
});
$(".form-right").keyup(function() {
  if ($(".form-left").val() && $(".form-right").val()) {
    $('.btn-select').attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('.btn-select').attr('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-left" type="text">
<input class="form-right" type="text">
<button class="btn-select" disabled>Посчитать</button>

<div class="popup-economy" style="display: none">
  <div class="price-left"></div>
  <div class="price-right"></div>
  <p class="economy"></p>
  <div class="sum"></div>
</div>

<div class="warning" style="display: none">
  <div class="price-left"></div>
  <div class="price-right"></div>
  <p class="economy">Возможно вы ошиблись</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Не подскажите как сделать еще что бы кнопка .btn-select была активна когда заполнены два input'а, если у нее стоит атрибут disabled?

Comment: @RavenTheX Обновил ответ

Comment: А как сделать что бы процент после запятой был не больше трех символов?

Comment: Можно использовать `.toFixed(2)` для переменной `sum`. В скобках цифра, это кол-во знаков после запятой

Comment: Либо `(parseInt(sum*100))/100`

Answer (score 3):

Легкая модификация кода @nicolaa - включение/выключение кнопки в 3 строки вместо 14

```js
$(".form-left,.form-right").keyup(function() { //Отслеживаем нажатие клавиш
    $('.btn-select').attr('disabled', !($(".form-left").val() && $(".form-right").val()) ); // Включаем|Выключаем кнопку
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-left" type="text">
<input class="form-right" type="text">
<button class="btn-select" disabled>Посчитать</button>

<div class="popup-economy" style="display: none">
  <div class="price-left"></div>
  <div class="price-right"></div>
  <p class="economy"></p>
  <div class="sum"></div>
</div>

<div class="warning" style="display: none">
  <div class="price-left"></div>
  <div class="price-right"></div>
  <p class="economy">Возможно вы ошиблись</p>
</div>
```